# Postgresql script adding parameter to \copy command

Tags: postgresql

I am running on a postgresql server version 9.6, and I am using psql.

I am trying to write a script that automatically imports a bunch of CSV files. The requirements are that it it is a single SQL script that a user can run that does not have access  to the server itself.

This means that the copy command results in a permissions denied error. So I have to use the \copy command.

This all works fine and dandy, but the script now contains a lot of hard coded directory names.

This is the basic code that I am trying:

```
\set test '\'' :in_dir /parcel.csv '\'';
select :test ;
\copy temp_table from :test with delimiter ',' quote '"' csv;
```

the result is a

> psql:d:/test.sql:20: :test: No such file or directory

I've tried moving it to a function with an 'execute format' statement, but \copy does not work there.
A regular copy results in a permission denied.

Is there any way to make the directory parameterized?